# Insert Data from Datagridview to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I want to ask something about my code. I want to insert data from datagridview to excel using C#. In my datagridview I have

```
WSID  Lokasi  Saldo
1234   A       200
5678   B       300
```

And I want to insert WSID data to excel file that has header WSID, like

```
WSID  
1234   
5678
```

I code like

```
 private void InputScheduleSaldoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string inputdata;

            OleDbConnection kon2 = new OleDbConnection(konekpengisian);
            OleDbCommand commanddir2 = kon2.CreateCommand();

            for (int i = 0; i < ViewDataSaldoGV.Rows.Count; i++ )
            {

                commanddir2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Saldo$] ([WSID]) VALUES (wsid)";
                commanddir2.Parameters.AddWithValue("wsid", ViewDataSaldoGV.Rows[i].Cells["WSID"].Value);
                textBox1.Text = i.ToString();

                kon2.Open();
                commanddir2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                kon2.Close();

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil disimpan");
}
```

And in my excel file it become

```
WSID  
1234
1234
```

Can anyone help me to solve my problem ?

Comment: Try adding @ before your parameters `INSERT INTO [Saldo$] ([WSID]) VALUES (@wsid)` and also here `commanddir2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wsid", ViewDataSaldoGV.Rows[i].Cells["WSID"].Value);`

Comment: It's the same. Can you help me ?